# warning MSB3290: Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I was trying to add the System_Windows_Forms reference COM reference. But when i add it i get this error

```
Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2701,5): warning MSB3290: Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.
```

By the way, i am on a Console App, and for some reason instead of seeing a `Reference` node i see a `Dependencies` node, although i doubt that matters.

I also tried adding a different reference, `Interop.IWshRunTimeLibrary` works, but `System.Drawing.dll` doesnt

Comment: can you post how you're using your references in your code?  If you're running a console app you wouldn't be able to reference or load `System.Windows.Forms` dependencies.

Comment: `By the way, i am on a Console App, and for some reason instead of seeing a Reference node i see a Dependencies node, although i doubt that matters.` I believe that is because you are used to .NET Framework projects but your current project is .NET Core, and it can matter a lot. Please read more about the differences between .NET Framework and .NET Core (or create a .NET Framework project instead if it is for windows only).

Comment: That's because you are using a .Net core project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a console app you wouldn't be able to reference or load `System.Windows.Forms` dependencies.  Equally `System.Drawing` as those are directly related to `Form` and `Form` objects and therefore aren't accessible as console dependencies, and is why you're getting that error.

**Update:** To check for key presses within a console app use `Console.Readkey()` Method. Here's an example of using `Console.ReadKey()`

```
using System;

class CheckKeyPress
{
    public static void Main()
   {
     ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
     Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true; //Prevents from ending if CTL+C is pressed

      Console.Writeline("Press any CTL, ALT, or SHIFT");
      Console.Writeline("Press ESC key to quit: \n");
   do
     {
       cki = Console.ReadKey();
      Console.Write("You Pressed: ");
      if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.ALT) != 0) Console.Write("ALT+");
      if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.SHIFT) != 0) Console.Write("SHIFT+");
      if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.CTL) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
      Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
    } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, but i really need to use the reference. Is there some way i could use it in a console app? And what's the reason for not being able to use certain references in console apps? If no way to use in a console app, whats the closest project type to a console app?

Comment: What is it that you’re trying to do within a console application that would require you to need Forms dependencies? Secondly why wouldn’t you just make a Form based application?

Comment: i am trying to check for key presses, is that even possible within a console app?

Comment: it works but it doesn't work when i press Alt, Shift, or Control alone (anyway to fix?). I also recommend to say `Console.ReadKey(true)` so that it doesn't print the key you pressed unless you tell it to

Comment: You could use a statement like `If (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)` You would need to make a reference to `PresentationCore.dll` in order to access `Input.Keyboard`.  This assembly is not referenced by default within a console application. You can see documentation for the keyboard here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1